# Argparse input executes command it should not

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I stumbled across this odd behavior by accident while working on a project. Here is the demo code that will reproduce the same issue -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Random observations')

parser.add_argument('-g', '--get', help='Get n of something')
parser.add_argument('-c','--create', help='Create something')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['get']:
    print(f"Retrieved {args['get']} resources...")

if args['create']:
    print(f"Created resource..{args['create']}")
```

I made the script executable just for brevity using `chmod +x filename`
Now, this is where it gets wierd. If i run the script like this -
`` $ ./so -c "Calling `./so -g 5`" ``
I get the output as -
    `Created resource..Calling Retrieved 5 resources...`
**Why is the command in string getting executed**, shouldn't it just go in as a string and come out as a string ?

I did a few more experiments and here are my findings:
Command -
`` $ ./so -c """Calling `./so -g 5`""" ``
Output
`Created resource..Calling Retrieved 5 resources...`

Command -
`` $./so -c '''Calling `./so -g 5`''' ``
Output -
`` Created resource..Calling `./so -g 5` ``

Why is the last one working as expected and not the others?

P.S I do not know the necessary tags for this question, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands

Comment: You seem to be expecting shell quotation to work like Python string literals. It doesn't.

Comment: Try echo rather than your script.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for letting me know what I was actually doing. However, that still doesn't clarify why the last one doen't output the same as the ones before if everything inside backtick is supposed to be executed? I have edited the question to now reflect its opposite behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: @user2357112 That explains it. Would you like to answer this question? I will accept it. Or should i delete it?

Comment: In a case like this I posters to print `sys.argv` to see what strings get passed into Python, and `args` (before or after `vars`) to see exactly what the parser produced.